# have less read from stdin, but show filename

Tags: unix, command-line

I want to syntax highlight a bunch of files and page through the output.
The problems is that less won't show a filename if it is reading from stdin.

How can I have less read from stdin and still show the filename?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
for f in *.py; do
    pygmentize "$f" | less -mR
done
```

Comment: `echo -n $f; pygmentize "$f" | less -mR`

Comment: @mpez0, you mean `{ echo -n $f; pygmentize "$f"; } | less -mR`

Comment: @glennjackman that would feed the echo output to less; I thought OP simply wants the output to show the filename. Either way works, depending on what's wanted.

Comment: @Dan, where do you want to see the filename in less?

Comment: echoing the name doesn't work.  less takes over the whole screen and you can't see it.  When you run less on a file, it shows the filename in the status bar at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temporary directory and put the files *there*, making `less` see those as the "real" files.

For example (on systems providing [`mktemp`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mktemp&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2011-current&arch=default&format=html) able to make a directory):

```
#!/bin/sh
mydir=$(mktemp -d)
trap "cd; rm -rf $mydir" EXIT INT QUIT
for f in *.py; do
    pygmentize "$f" >$mydir/"$f"
    (cd $mydir && less -mR "$f" )
done
```

Comment: That's one solution and nicely written.  I was hoping to not have to do that, but you make it look pretty easy.

Comment: It was easily written - the only awkward part is which details are portable to your system for the `trap` command (I checked this with `dash`).

Comment: I ended up doing one refinement.  If there is a path to the file, we need to strip path off first.